# Browser prompt is not showing in my Tauri app for Mac

Tags: javascript, svelte, prompt, tauri

I have built a webpage using the Svelte framework. I want to be able to use the application both as a webpage, and as a desktop app on both Windows and Mac. To achieve this, I build it as a Tauri app.

Everything is working well. The webpage looks good on both Windows and Mac, and the desktop application is working for both as well.

To keep it simple, I run a function which in turn opens the prompt() function to add names or rename files. This is where I am now encountering a problem.

On the web and Windows version, everything works well. The prompt appears, I enter the name, and I click OK. The name is then updated.

However, on Mac, the prompt does not appear, and I get an error because the new name field is empty, and the rest of the function keeps running.

Is there any way to use prompt() in a Tauri app on Mac, or do I have to build my own sort of prompt?

To recreate it, add a button that runs a function including the prompt(). Build it as a Tauri app on Mac, run it, and click the button.

```
<button on:click={() => prompt()}></button>
```

The prompt will appear on a Windows version, however, it will not appear on Mac.

Comment: Edited the question now adding a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

There are already more native versions of `alert` and `confirm` in `@tauri-apps/api/dialog` but [`prompt` is currently missing](https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/issues/4783).

Your best bet is probably to implement your own (using Promises with `async`/`await` as regular user interaction cannot be blocking like `window.prompt`).